# How to change the foreground/background color of the find text box in a FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

I am using a FlowDocumentReader to view some text, when I try typing in the find text searchbox the foreground is white and so is the background. How can I modify either the foreground or background? I tried modifying the Background and Foreground colors for both FlowDocument and FlowDocumentReader but that doesn't work.

```
<FlowDocumentReader  Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="1" Name="flowDocReader" IsFindEnabled="True">
  <FlowDocument Name="flowDoc"/>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

**Typing**
[image]

**Dropwdown arrow**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the issue was MahApps was set to Dark Theme, So my controls use white as the Foreground color.  Simply changing the theme from dark to light did the trick.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml" />
```

Comment: I am getting the same issue but I dont use MahApps , its a simple WPF application, but the problem is exact same as you described, how to make text in find box visible? how to make context menu text visible?